# XFCE: automatically enable/disable touchpad depending on mouse presence

Tags: mouse, xfce, touchpad

I'm using the latest XFCE4 under Linux. My laptop has a touchpad, but I only want it to be enabled if the USB mouse is not connected. I know how to manually control this, but I'd like to find a way for the touchpad to auto-disable when a USB mouse is plugged in and auto-enable when the USB mouse is disconnected.

I can't find anything in the XFCE4 settings that controls this.

Is there any way I can have this auto-enable/disable capability for the touchpad?

Thank you very much.